# How can I "split" a ground wire

Tags: electrical, lighting

I am moving a friend of mine into their new apartment and we need to put up a new light fixture into the bathroom. The bathroom has nothing but a light... 'hole'. There are no wall sockets or anything, and I believe this room has its own separate breaker (we cut off the power to the entire apartment when working on electricals). But the lamp has a LED strip inside so it needs a ground wire.
The problem is, there isn't a loose wire hanging in the ceiling.

This is a 3D recreation so please bear with me.
[image: Yup.]

This is pretty much what it looks like. (yes the wires do actually come out of the walls)

How can I still ground the lamp by cutting the green wire without breaking the loop? Is there a splitter piece or something?

Thank you for helping.

PS: The light fixture does not have a green screw or anything. A wire has to be screwed into the connector.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of the lamp connections? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the situation in the ceiling? Also, where on the planet are you?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this before in rentals I own, lights with no boxes, I wouldn't do it but that must be the local building code. If you cut the ground wire you can make a pigtail to reconnect the ground and the new fixture. The wire nuts for ground (green) have a hole in the top to feed the new fixture which makes it easier.